# C++ Explicit Template instantiation with double and long double

Tags: c++, templates

So I wrote this template function which is for floating points.

In h:

```
template <typename FloatingPointType>
double nextLow(FloatingPointType a);
```

In Cpp:

```
template <typename FloatingPointType>
FloatingPointType nextLow(FloatingPointType a)
{
    return std::nextafter(a, std::numeric_limits<FloatingPointType>::lowest());
}
```

Now I thought I could explicitly instantiate this one for all floating point types:

```
template<> float nextLow<float>(float a);
template<> double nextLow<double>(double a);
template<> long double nextLow<long double>(long double a);
```

However in the row:

```
template<> double nextLow<double>(double a);
```

I get this from intellisense:

```
"more than one instance of overloaded function  matches the argument list:"
```

And this from the compiler:

```
error: ambiguous template specialization ‘nextLow<double>’ for ‘double bricks::nextLow(double)’
   39 |     template<> double nextLow<double>(double a);
```

why is that so? Do `double` and `long double` get threaten as the same type?

Comment: Remove the `<>`

Comment: doesn't look like it solves the problem

Comment: @Sandro4912 paste the actual code that issues the error

Comment: The code looks ok - https://godbolt.org/z/oYccnY

Comment: intellisense has more false positive that true compiler.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the Issue in the header file.

There it states:

```
template <typename FloatingPointType>
double nextLow(FloatingPointType a);
```

But of course it should be:

```
template <typename FloatingPointType>
FloatingPointType nextLow(FloatingPointType a);
```

Also the `<>` need to be dropped otherwise the compiler complains on usage of the template.
So this:

```
template<> float nextLow<float>(float a);
template<> double nextLow<double>(double a);
template<> long double nextLow<long double>(long double a);
```

Should be changed to this:

```
template float nextLow<float>(float a);
template double nextLow<double>(double a);
template long double nextLow<long double>(long double a);
```